# Can I have /Users as my home folder?

Tags: macbook-pro

My home directory location is set to `/Users`, so whole `/Users` folder. I know that each user normally has their own folder in the `/Users` folder, but would it be ok if I'm using my MacBook alone?

Also, is there any problem if my account name and the home folder name are not same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with this. Account name and home folder name can be different.

It’s okay even if you are using your MacBook alone.

Comment: Not sure about the last part. Isn‘t it rather only ok as long as one uses a Mac with *one* user account only?

Comment: Oh .. now I see the problem. I tried to update the software to Catalina but I cannot update it. What should I do?